# jquery disabling all events and enabling

Tags: jquery, click

Im trying to disable property using jquery .prop function. 
i used :
 `$("#a, #b").prop('disabled', true);`
                                                                                                                   now, if I check it on Chrome Developer Tools i can see disabled property isnt applied on both of the elements. when i entered it hardcoded, events still fired as if it wasnt disabled.

```
$("#a").click(function(){
    alert("ASD");
    });
```

still fired.

Comment: What kind of elements are `#a` and `#b`? Not all elements support that property.

Comment: Yeah, those don't support that property. You have to use a flag or unbind the event handler.

Comment: What do you expect disabled will do on td or img tag?

Comment: i would really love to stay off unbind click, flag just wont do the work i need to prevent the click itself.
@roasted they have click events

Comment: Your code is working see http://jsfiddle.net/uBDHY/

Comment: Are you wanting to detach/attach event handlers or disable/enable input elements?

Comment: its not input elements, those are TDs and IMGs when assigned id that have .click event

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already discussed, the `disabled` property is not supported by images and table cells.

If you don't want to unbind the event handler, you can set a flag. You can then prevent executing the event handler and propagation of the event by testing for the flag inside the handler:

```
$("#a, #b").data('disabled', true);

// ...    

$("#a").click(function(e){
    if ($(this).data('disabled')) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        return;
        // or just `return false;` instead of explicitly calling the methods
    }
    alert("ASD");
});
```

---

[Beetroot-Beetroot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1142252/beetroot-beetroot) made a good suggestion in their comment: If you add and remove a class instead of using `.data`, then you can also *style the element accordingly at the same time*.

It would work very similarly:

```
$("#a, #b").addClass('disabled');
// and .removeClass or .toggleClass to remove the class

// ... 

$("#a").click(function(e){
    if ($(this).hasClass('disabled')) {
       // ...
    }
    // ...
});
```

Comment: i like the data way, looks like the more appropriate

Comment: a `return false` causes an implicit `preventDefault` and `stopPropagation`, doesn't it?

Comment: @Alnitak: Yes, but I like to be explicit :) At least in this case. I added a comment though.

Comment: If a 'disabled' class was used instead of `.data('disabled')`, then you would have a single mechanism for determining appearance and functionality.

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot: Good point! Updated my answer, but if you want to provide your own, go ahead and I will revert the edit (and upvote yours).

Comment: Thank you Felix but I think it's better as it is, with both approaches together in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

"Normal" elements don't support the `disabled` property, that's normally used on *input* elements.

You have a few options:

1. deregister every single event handler with `.off()`
2. place a child element of the exact same size on top of the elements that will receive all events and prevent them from propagating to their parent.
3. use a flag which the event handler can read when it's fired to decide whether to proceed or not

Option 2 is often used by "modal" dialog boxes which cover the entire window with an overlay to prevent events from reaching the page.

Answer (score 0):

your mentioned elements dont support that property. You can instead toggle a class.

```
$('#a').click(function() {
if ($(this).hasClass('yes')) {...} else {...}
});
```

and add/ remove the class

Answer (score -1):

If "disabled" is an valid attribute/property for #a and #b, try this:

```
$("#a, #b").prop("disabled", "disabled");
```

You cannot disable every element.

Comment: Because `disabled` is a property accepting a boolean value. You might be talking about the HTML *attribute*, but `.prop` is setting the DOM property, not the attribute.

Comment: @Mr.Bombastic because `disabled` is a _boolean_ property.  It happens that your string "disabled" gets converted to a boolean `true`, but it's more luck than judgement.